# Eclipse ADT plugin graphical layout: how to show grid lines

Tags: xml, eclipse, layout, adt

I'm working on an Android app project, and for the layout of my activity I'd like to be able to see the grid lines for my LinearLayouts and views and such. I've seen in tutorials a button that displays gridlines around every view. I don't see it in my editor, and I'm wondering how I can find this feature.

I'm running Eclipse Indigo with ADT plugin 16.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable grid view in a device,while testing apps.The feature has deprecated in the emulator.